# FOSS VoIP software client suite - easy to use

Tags: open-source, cross-platform, voip

I'm looking for a FOSS VoIP software client suite that i can use to talk with my family, they are not always tech-savvy so ease-of-use is important

("software client suite": please see list of platforms below)

#### Features

- Easy to use
- Easy to set up (i am not available to help them IRL)
- Audio (video not needed)
- FOSS
- Availability of cost-free server where we can create accounts
- (less important: text chat built-in)

#### Platforms

These are the platforms we would like support for:

- Ubuntu
- Windows 7
- Android 4+
- (less important: MacOS)

(The tech might be using SIP, XMPP+extension, or something else, this is not important)

What can you recommend that we use? Grateful for help!

Comment: perhaps skim my answer here "https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/31561/open-source-self-hosted-encrypted-chat-system/31580#31580" on using ChatSecure (I believe VoIP works pretty good now as well).

Comment: as they provide a native client for every platform you mentioned (which minimizes confusion for tech-unsavvy users) you may try [Linphone](https://www.linphone.org/) (SIP-clients).